# Rails filtering by a has_and_belongs_to_many attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bit of a problem! I have a Place model and a Category model which are connected through has_and_belongs_to_many. I wish to be able to filter out all places which belong to atleast one of the categories in a given array (int array of ids). So far I've only been able to filter by a single category with the following code:

```
@places = Place.find(:all, :include => :categories, :conditions => { "categories_places.category_id" => id})
```

so basically instead of id I want ids. I hope there are some rails experts here who can help! I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick nicely.

```
some_array_of_ids = [1, 2, 3]
@places = Place.find(:all, :include => :categories, :conditions => ['categories.id IN (?)', some_array_of_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @bor1s for the quick responses. I can't try the solution until tomorrow but I have no doubt it should work :) Unfortunately I can't upvote yet because of too low rep :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@places = Place.find(:all, :include => :categories, :conditions => ["categories_places.category_id IN ?", int])
```

where `int` - your array of ids

Answer (score 0):

or if you want it in a scope for chaining

```
some_array_of_ids = [1,2,3]
@places = Place.includes(:categories).where('categories.id IN (?)', some_array_of_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails5 it can be like this:

```
some_array_of_ids = [1,2,3]
@places = Place.joins(:categories).where('categories.id': some_array_of_ids)
```

And I use `scope` in model:

```
scope :by_categories, ->(category_ids) { joins(:categories).where('categories.id': category_ids) }
```

So you can select `places` you need this way:

```
some_array_of_ids = [1,2,3]
@places = Place.by_categories(some_array_of_ids)
```